# Implementation of simple polling of results file

Tags: r, debugging, synchronization, polling, control-flow

For one of my dissertation's *data collection* modules, I have implemented a simple **polling mechanism**. This is needed, because I make each data collection request (one of many) as SQL query, submitted via Web form, which is simulated by **RCurl** code. The server processes each request and generates a text file with results at a specific URL (`RESULTS_URL` in code below). Regardless of the request, URL and file name are the same (I cannot change that). Since processing time for different data requests, obviously, is different and some requests may take significant amount of time, my `R` code needs to "know", when the results are ready (file is re-generated), so that it can retrieve them. The following is my solution for this problem.

```
POLL_TIME <- 5 # polling timeout in seconds
```

In function `srdaRequestData()`, before making data request:

```
# check and save 'last modified' date and time of the results file
# before submitting data request, to compare with the same after one
# for simple polling of results file in srdaGetData() function
beforeDate <- url.exists(RESULTS_URL, .header=TRUE)["Last-Modified"]
beforeDate <<- strptime(beforeDate, "%a, %d %b %Y %X", tz="GMT")

<making data request is here>
```

In function `srdaGetData()`, called after `srdaRequestData()`

```
# simple polling of the results file
repeat {
  if (DEBUG) message("Waiting for results ...", appendLF = FALSE)
  afterDate <- url.exists(RESULTS_URL, .header=TRUE)["Last-Modified"]
  afterDate <-  strptime(afterDate, "%a, %d %b %Y %X", tz="GMT")
  delta <- difftime(afterDate, beforeDate, units = "secs")
  if (as.numeric(delta) != 0) { # file modified, results are ready
    if (DEBUG) message(" Ready!")
    break
  }
  else { # no results yet, wait the timeout and check again
    if (DEBUG) message(".", appendLF = FALSE)
    Sys.sleep(POLL_TIME)
  }
}

<retrieving request's results is here>
```

The module's main flow/sequence of events is linear, as follows:

```
Read/update configuration file
Authenticate with the system
Loop through data requests, specified in configuration file (via lapply()),
  where for each request perform the following:
  {
    ...
    Make request: srdaRequestData()
    ...
    Retrieve results: srdaGetData()
    ...
  }
```

The **issue** with the code above is that it doesn't seem to be working **as expected**: upon making data request, the code should print "Waiting for results ..." and then, periodically checking the results file for being modified (re-generated), print progress dots until the results are ready, when it prints confirmation. However, the **actual behavior** is that the code waits long time (I intentionally made one request a long-running), *not printing anything*, but then, apparently retrieves results and prints both "Waiting for results ..." and " Ready" *at the same time*.

It seems to me that it's some kind of *synchronization* issue, but I can't figure out what exactly. Or, maybe it's *something else* and I'm somehow missing it. **Your advice and help will be much appreciated!**

Comment: The messages might be getting buffered. And perhaps they are not writing out to the screen as soon as they are generated. But since i can't run the code and test it, it's hard to say. If all the files are fine and just the messages are backup, that seems like the most likely case. Sometimes sending a `\n` might trigger a buffer flush.

Comment: @MrFlick: Interesting, I haven't thought about output's buffering! You're right, again! The results seem to be fine, just displaying of the progress is not consistent with reality. But, that's OK for now - I have too much of other - more important - stuff to worry about... :-). Greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment to the question, I believe `MrFlick` solved the issue:  the polling logic appears to be functional, but **the problem is that the progress messages are *out of synch* with current events on the system**.

By default, **the R console output is buffered**. This is by design: to speed things up and avoid the distracting flicker that may be associated with frequent messages etc.  We tend to forget this fact, particularly after we've been using R in a very interactive fashion, running various ad-hoc statement at the console (the console buffer is automatically flushed just before returning the `>` prompt).

It is however possible to get `message()` and more generally console output in "real time" by either explicitly flushing the console after each critical output statement, using the `flush.console()` function, or by disabling buffering at the level of the R GUI (right-click when on the console, see `Buffered output Ctrl W` item.  This is also available in the `Misc` menu)

Here's a toy example of the explicit use of flush.console.  Note the use of `cat()` rather than `message()`  as the former doesn't automatically add a CR/LF to the output.  The latter however is useful however because its messages can be suppressed with `suppressMessages()` and the like.  Also as shown in the comment you can cat the "\b" (backspace) character to make the number overwrite one another.

```
CountDown <- function() {
  for (i in 9:1){
    cat(i)
    # alternatively to cat(i) use:  message(i)
    flush.console()    # <<<<<<<  immediate ouput to console.
    Sys.sleep(1)
    cat(" ")   # also try cat("\b") instead ;-)
  }
  cat("... Blast-off\n")
}
```

The output is the following, what is of course not evident in this print-out is that it took 10 seconds overall with one number printed every second, before the final "Blast off"; do remove the flush.console() statement and the output will come at once, after 10 seconds, i.e. when the function terminates (unless console is not buffered at the level of the GUI).

> CountDown()
>    9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 ... Blast-off